# Need a complex cssSelector to differentiate between two save buttons on same page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have two save buttons on the same page but I need to click the bottom one.

This is the first:

```
 <a href="javascript:addPhoneNumber('edit')">
 <img width="60" height="19" border="0" title="Save" alt="Save" src="../images/save.gif">
```

This is the second:

```
 <a href="javascript:onSave()">
 <img width="60" height="19" border="0" title="Save" alt="Save" src="../images/save.gif">
```

I need to click the second one. I tried this but no dice:

```
 WebElement foo5 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
       .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href*='javascript:onSave()'][alt='Save']")));
 foo5.click();
```

Any pointers? I'm horrible with cssselectors.

Answer (score 2):

Hi please do it like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // as both button have same title so take them inside the list 
        List<WebElement> mybuttons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[type='Save']"));
        // Now to verify total number of buttons with type attribute as save
        System.out.println("Total buttons on the page is : " +mybuttons.size());

        // now we can click buttons on the basis of index as they are inside the 
        // List now Note in java index starts form zero (0)

        mybuttons.get(0).click();  // to click on the First button
        mybuttons.get(1).click();  // to click on the Second button
    }
```